# Linking publishing's xsl files?

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I'm working on customization of some ContentByQueryWebPart.

This customization consists in defining custom `contentquerymain.xsl` and `itemstyle.xsl` file.

However, from one customization to another, only small changes are applied. For example, depending on the webpart, I'm changing the `beginList` variable to apply custom css class, or I add some custom markup.

The side effect, is that if I change something that is shared between all instances, I have to report the changes in all xsl files.

Is there a clean way to factorize standard xsl templates?

I've seen the `<xsl:import>` node, but I could not make it work.

**[Edit]** After some test, I discover that I can "import" the xsl will something like :

```
<xsl:import 
    href="/sites/mysitecollection/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ContentQueryMainCustom.xsl"
    />
```

However, this is not dynamic, I have to know the site collection url in advance to make it works